# Bash script function with parameters

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function 'lf' which will list only the files in a directory but which will will accept standard options for ls so that I can use them both in the same way.

I have the command

```
$ ls -p | grep -v /
```

which works just fine. The problem comes when I try to expand this so that the ls part accepts a command line option. I have defined the following function in my ~/.bashrc

```
 function lf(){
     ls -p "$1" | grep -v /
 }
```

which works fine if I just use it as lf. But, when I add an option, for instance -l to get long output, I get

```
$ lf -l
(standard input)
```

Changing the double quotes to single makes no difference; neither does enclosing the whole ls command in quotes.

If I type out the full command

```
$ ls -p -l | grep -v /
```

which is what I am assuming my code should expand to, it works fine. Google has been less than helpful in solving this. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Please run `(set -x ; lf -l)` and show the output. If you want only files, you could consider `find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec ls "$@" {} +`. Are you _sure_ you are running `lf` function and not something else? `(standard input)` would be consistent with `grep -l` output, as if you would erroneusly do `alias=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```bash
function lf {
    ls -p "$@" | grep -v /
}
```

`"$@"`, when quoted, expands into the function's arguments, exactly how they were given.

So you can then write this, and have your function run the way you expect

```bash
lf -l -a -t /tmp "$HOME/my file with spaces"
```

Comment: Also, when you use the `function` keyword, you don't need to use the parentheses. If you use parentheses, you don't need the function keyword.

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick - as I'm sure you knew it would! Although, for some strange reason (my computer is *very* strange) if I try and use function without the brackets or vice versa, it throws an 'unexpected token' error. Don't ask, I don't know why. I've just learned to live with it's idiosyncracies.

Comment: OK, I won't ask why. What bash version do you use?

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I suspect you're missing the space between the function name and the opening brace: `function foobar{ echo hello; }` errors with `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'` -- braces are actually reserved words, and they need to be surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, where you check to see if $1 is passed in or not.

```
function lf() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    ls -p "$1" | grep -v /
  else
    ls -p | grep -v /
  fi
}
```